# Subset data frame R based in two conditions in two different columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) which looks like this:

```
c1  c2    c3

100 FALSE  a

110 FALSE  b

120 FALSE  c

130 FALSE  d

150 FALSE  e

160 FALSE  f

170 FALSE  g

180 FALSE  h

190 TRUE   i

200 FALSE  l

210 FALSE  m

220 FALSE  n

230 FALSE  o

240 FALSE  p

250 FALSE  q

260 FALSE  r

270 FALSE  s
```

I would like to select a certain number of rows which are preceding and which are following the row with "TRUE" in column c2. For instance I want to have the rows having in c1 with values of 190 (the row with TRUE) minus 40 or 190 plus 40.

Expected output:

```
150 FALSE  e

160 FALSE  f

170 FALSE  g

180 FALSE  h

190 TRUE   i

200 FALSE  l

210 FALSE  m

220 FALSE  n

230 FALSE  o
```

Comment: The condition is not clear,  Are these values in 'c1' in sequence ?

Comment: yes, increasing in sequence, from lowest to highest

Comment: May be `i1 <- which(df1$c2);df1[sort(unique(unlist(lapply(i1, function(i) (i-4):(i+4))))),]`

Comment: ok I will try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the 'base' c1 first using

`base <- df[which(df$c2), 'c1']`

Then use `which` again to get your desired rows.

`out <- df[which((df$c1 <= base + 40) & (df$c1 >= base - 40)),]`

Hope this helps :-)